# findDOMNode error on React material-ui select menu

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using the [select component](https://material-ui.com/components/selects/) here the exact markup

```
        <FormControl
            variant="outlined"
            className={classes.formControl}
            error={errors.title ? true : false}
          >
            <InputLabel htmlFor="title">Who are you?</InputLabel>
            <Select
              labelId="titleLabel"
              id="title"
              value={state.title ? state.title : 'Example1'}
              onChange={handleChange}
              label="Who are you?"
            >
              <MenuItem value={`Example1`}>Example1</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={`Example2`}>Example2</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={`Example3`}>Example3</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={`other`}>other</MenuItem>
            </Select>
            {errors.title && <FormHelperText>{errors.title}</FormHelperText>}
          </FormControl>
```

Then I keep getting the following error and not sure how to fix this

```
index.js:1 Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of Transition which is inside StrictMode. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference. Learn more about using refs safely here: fb.me/react-strict-mode-find-node
```

Comment: They'll be fixing this in [Material-Ui v5 #13394](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/13394)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The error is coming because Material UI using [react-transition-group](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/7cc9a9949126c5199e3cb341e12d4274f9895036/packages/material-ui/package.json#L51) component is which trying to use `findDOMNode` method which is deprecated and they haven't fixed it yet.

But, this error is coming only in **strict mode** in React and you can consider it just as a warning since it's says that the method is going to be deprecated but if the functionality of component if fine, you have nothing to worry about as it work just fine with current version. You can track this issue [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/issues/429).

Will update the answer when I find the real solution to this. Hope it gives you some idea.

[Related open issue](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/issues/429)

Comment: @AliRehman you don't get the error in production or non-strict mode!

Comment: I solved this by using Native Select https://material-ui.com/components/selects/#native-select

Comment: Thanks @AliRehman using the `native` Select worked here as well!

Comment: any updates on this? I have searched endlessly and "possible" solutions for it using CSSTransition does not work either.

Comment: @TommyRivera Not yet. Since it's not a blocker, they haven't picked it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the component `<NativeSelect/>` instead of `<Select/>`.  In my experience it does not generate the `findDOMNode` error.